# Income, Expenditure, EBIT Visualization in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Could any one please suggest the best way to visualize Income, Expenditure and EBIT numbers for 5 Business Units? Thanks in advance

Comment: To get response for your queries you need atleast provide dummy data and rough picture of the report. Else how will you expect people to know what you want

Answer (score 0):

At our company, I use a dual-axis bar chart to represent this.

[image]

Total sales is in orange and the EBIT in blue.

This shows how each branch compares with one another in terms of sales and EBIT, and also shows how much of sales makes it to EBIT at each branch.